# Xcode: External build configuration for framework target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, build

We have a `Filters` framework that contains many image processing filters (written in Swift and Metal) and the resources they require (like ML models and static images). But not every app we have uses all the filters in `Filters`. Rather we want to only build and bundle the required filters and resources that are needed by the app.

The only way we can think of to achieve that is to create different framework targets in Xcode, one for each app. But that would require that the `Filters` framework project “knows” all of its consumers (apps) and we would rather like to avoid that. Especially since the filters are in a separate repository.

Is there a way to, for instance, pass some kind of configuration file to the framework that is used at build time to decide which files to build and bundle?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Target Membership to assign files into specific targets. See image below.

[image]

Make sure you are on the `File Inspector` tab on the right side of Xcode. Select the files you want to limit to a target and in the `Target Membership` area, you can select which target the selected file belongs to or don't belong to. For public resources, make sure to select `public` for the visibility scope.

For files that don't require compilation, e.g. image files, once you've selected the target membership, the file will be automatically added to the `Build Phases`' `Copy Bundle Resources` area.

**Alternative One**

Alternatively, you can use add a `Copy Files Phase` in the `Build Phases`. With the `Copy Files Phase`, you can copy files to subdirectories instead of the root of the framework bundle.

**Alternative Two**

Yet another way is to add a `Run Script Phase` in the `Build Phases`. The script can be in any language but usually shell script. You can do whatever you need in the script including compiling code manually but you need to know where the files goes by using environment variables and placed the files in the correct location. I think this will be the most manual and most hassle to use for selecting files based on targets.

**Alternative Three**

If you really want to go fancy, you can even break down all the components into targets and use `Aggregate target` to tie the different components into the target you are building for. I would not recommend this usually and reserve this for very special needs that other methods could not achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I was hoping I could avoid introducing new targets to the `Filters` project. I would instead like to have a means to pass some kind of build configuration file down from the framework user that is used during framework compilation.

Comment: That means you don't compile the Filters framework independent of the apps projects? Meaning the Filters framework project is embedded into your apps project and get build automatically every time the apps are build? If you use git as your source control, I presume you have the Filters framework as a submodule of the apps repo?

Comment: Exactly right. But I would have preferred if the Filters project would not require knowledge of the apps that are using it. My solution right now is to have an extra app-specific target of Filters for each app in the Filters project. That works, but I would have preferred something like `configure` + `make`, if that makes sense.

Comment: In that case, you may want to check out the external build system. With the external build system can specify any build system including `make`. The only problem is that your `Filters` framework is a Xcode project. To use an external build system to build your framework, you will need to replicate all the Xcode build steps on the external build system.

Comment: PS: The external build system need to be added to the app project instead of the framework project to leave the framework not knowing about the different apps. Also the app project need to turn off building the framework by excluding the submodule from the Xcode project and only exist on git level.